# ActiveMQ 5.16.1 - Messages get stuck

Tags: microservices, activemq-classic, messagebroker

We're currently having problems with our ActiveMQ 5.16.1 which suddenly starts piling up messages without any apparent reason. The following image shows the ActiveMQ QueueSize:

[image: Messages get stuck]

The ActiveMQ is used as JMS message broker without any other components for e.g. high availability or load balancing. Several producers (in total and worst case around 20) produce small/simple JSON messages which are send to the broker and consumed by a JAVA-based microservice. The microservice processes the message and saves the data to an Oracle database. Average processing time for one request is about 30ms. From those 20 producers only some are active at the same time which might vary between 2 and 10 producers. Each producer sends a message every 3 secondes resulting in 20 messages/min per producer. E.g.: having 10 producers the broker will get 200 messages/min or 30 messages/sec. Preserving the order is crucital thus I'm working with JMSXGroupIds which works good so far. Messages are send via MQTT and routed (via Camel) to an JMS queue:

```xml
    <route id="handleData"> 
        <from uri="activemq://topic:some.topic.here?clientId=uniqueClientId" /> 
          <setHeader headerName="tName">
             <constant>ABC123</constant>
          </setHeader>
          <setHeader headerName="JMSXGroupId">
             <jsonpath>$.producerId</jsonpath>
          </setHeader>
        <to uri="activemq://queue:myQueue" />
    </route>
```

But for any reason the messages get stuck after some time and I can't find any significant hint why that happens. There is nothing in the log files nor the OS event log. I have to restart the ActiveMQ service in order to "reanimate" it. Afterwards all stuck messages will be processed and everything is working fine until the next "accident". This time it took about 10 days before the messages got stuck.

I already checked whether there might be a network or database-related issue. Even moved the ActiveMQ to a freshly new server in order to asure that nothing else is influencing the ActiveMQ processes. But I couldn't find any hints either. I watched the JVM, heap space growth, memory usage, etc. - everything unremarkable.

Does anybody has an idea what I could check additionally to find out what the problem is?

Comment: What does the consumer-count on the queue do during the time the messages start to accumulate?

Comment: @JustinBertram - remains unchanged (currently 8 out of 10 allowed). In addition I checked whether the client is considered as slow consumer - it isn't. Even though I didn't see any consumers which might have been considered as slow consumer I activated "abortSlowConsumerStrategy". Don't know if this helps, it's more a kind of desperate attempt to get a grip on it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the advisoryForSlowConsumer destinationPolicy setting for those topics and watch the topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.. for any enqueue counts that would indicate slow consumer occurred.

Your Camel route is almost identical to what a VirtualTopic does. You'll see better consistency with server-side routing in these types of scenarios, since there is no remote process (ie. Camel route) to manage connections, sessions, etc.

Bonus: MQTT transport supports using Virtual Topics to back-end the subscriptions so you any MQTT topic consumers would automatically pull from the queue.

ref: https://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations

Comment: Thx for your advice! I'll give it a try and see if it gets better. Currently the problem is still remaining. No consumer is encountered as slow consumer but stacking messages though. As soon as I restart the instance the messages are consumed and everything works fine until the next "crash".

Comment: Hi @Stoffelchen, did you get this issue fixed? I'm having the same issue. Was hoping you could share your fix - if you got it. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not fixed yet. It's weird. At the moment I suspect our Tomcat web server as the main problem. There is always one consumer connection that's prefetching messages but lacks processing them. All surrounding components (database, etc.) are acting normal. No long running operations, etc.
My next step is to get support from an external company which helps to configure our tomcat server. I know that there is a problem when having applications deployed via "hot deploy". Some say that this will result in memory leaks and my hope is that this is the major problem for our case.

Comment: @Stoffeichen Tip-- with hot deploy, you need to make sure an 'undeploy' will shutdown and turn off existing consumers. Sounds like you are on the right track if you see a leaked Consumer.

Comment: Thanks @Stoffelchen, we'll look in that space also - if we find anything - I'll reply here. But if you come across a fix -please share also.